# Почему не отображается иконка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, gui

Подскажите пожалуйста вот у меня есть проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я запускаю модуль `registration_window` открывается окно с кнопкой, когда я нажимаю на кнопку открывается окно модуля `main_window`, но почему то не отображается иконка `user.png`, хотя если отдельно запустить окно модуля `main_window`, то иконка отображается нормально.

У меня большая программа будет в которой пользователь проходит регистрацию и открывается главное окно программы, я хочу чтобы иконка отображалась, как это можно сделать.

**user.png**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**registration_window.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication)
from main_window import CentralWidget
import sys


class RegistrationWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RegistrationWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("")
        self.setObjectName('registration_window')
        self.setStyleSheet('''#registration_window {
                                background-color: #4dffff;    
        }''')
        self.main_window_app = CentralWidget()
        self.btn = QPushButton('Открыть')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.save_input_user_kbju)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(30, 30, 30, 30)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def save_input_user_kbju(self):
        self.close()
        self.main_window_app.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = RegistrationWindow()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main_window.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QHBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import sys


class CentralWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CentralWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.setWindowTitle('КБЖУ')
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ffffff;')

        self.frame_name = QFrame()
        self.frame_name.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.frame_name.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
                            border: 0px;
                            background-color: #9EFFFF;
        }''')

        self.icon_user = QLabel()
        self.icon_user.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage('icon_app/user.png')))
        self.label_name = QLabel('Имя')
        self.label_name.setStyleSheet('''QLabel {
                            color: #4f4a4a;
                            font-size: 20px;
        }''')

        #  Верхнее меню и имя
        self.name_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.name_layout.setSpacing(10)
        self.name_layout.addWidget(self.icon_user)
        self.name_layout.addWidget(self.label_name)
        self.name_layout.addStretch(1)
        self.frame_name.setLayout(self.name_layout)

        #  Главная форма
        self.layout_main_menu = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_main_menu.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 30)
        self.layout_main_menu.addWidget(self.frame_name, stretch=2)
        self.layout_main_menu.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(self.layout_main_menu)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = CentralWidget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте, так.

Обратите внимание, что запускать (откуда угодно) будем модуль **q1388871_main_window.py**:

**`C:\>`** `python D:\_Qt\__Qt\q1388871_main_window.py`

Проект у меня находится **`D:\_Qt\__Qt`**, изображения **`D:\_Qt\__Qt\icon_app`**

**q1388871_main_window.py**

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QFrame, 
    QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QHBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage

from q1388871_registration_window import RegistrationWindow                    # +++


dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))                          # !!! +++
directory = os.path.join(dir_path, 'icon_app')                                 # !!! +++
print(f'\n{dir_path} \n{directory}') 


class CentralWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CentralWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.setWindowTitle('КБЖУ')
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ffffff;')

        self.frame_name = QFrame()
        self.frame_name.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.frame_name.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
                            border: 0px;
                            background-color: #9EFFFF;
        }''')

        self.icon_user = QLabel()

#        self.icon_user.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage('icon_app/user.png')))
        self.icon_user.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(f'{directory}/user.png')))      # +++
# +++ -->                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  

        self.label_name = QLabel('Имя')
        self.label_name.setStyleSheet('''QLabel {
                            color: #4f4a4a;
                            font-size: 20px;
        }''')

        #  Верхнее меню и имя
        self.name_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.name_layout.setSpacing(10)
        self.name_layout.addWidget(self.icon_user)
        self.name_layout.addWidget(self.label_name)
        self.name_layout.addStretch(1)
        self.frame_name.setLayout(self.name_layout)

        #  Главная форма
        self.layout_main_menu = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_main_menu.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 30)
        self.layout_main_menu.addWidget(self.frame_name, stretch=2)
        self.layout_main_menu.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(self.layout_main_menu)

        
        self.registrationWindow = RegistrationWindow(self)                           # !!! +++
        self.registrationWindow.show()                                               # !!! +++
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = CentralWidget()
    
#    win.show()                                                                      # !!! ---

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1388871_registration_window.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication)

# - from q1388871_main_window import CentralWidget



class RegistrationWindow(QWidget):
#    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#        super(RegistrationWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    def __init__(self, parent):                                                # +++
        super().__init__()                                                     # +++
        self.parent = parent                                                   # +++

        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("")
        self.setObjectName('registration_window')
        self.setStyleSheet('''#registration_window {
                                background-color: #4dffff;    
        }''')
#-        self.main_window_app = CentralWidget()
        self.btn = QPushButton('Открыть')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.save_input_user_kbju)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(30, 30, 30, 30)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def save_input_user_kbju(self):
        self.close()
#-        self.main_window_app.show()
        self.parent.show()                                                     # +++
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = RegistrationWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> Я понимаю, то что если я в один пакет положу все модули то все работает, но мне нужно чтобы работала так как у меня пакеты сделаны в проекте, и у меня запускается первым регистрация а потом главное окно, а вы просто все поняли местами и в один пакет положили, но у меня в настоящей программе будут десятки модулей в разных пакетах

Вы не поняли мой посыл. Да, я не разместил модули как у вас в проекте, но я предполагал, что вы это сделаете самостоятельно. Теперь я разместил все как у вас. Я изменил только одну строчку:

**q1388871_main_window.py**

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QFrame, 
    QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QHBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage

from authentication_window.q1388871_registration_window import RegistrationWindow    # +++
#--> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))                          # !!! +++
directory = os.path.join(dir_path, 'icon_app')                                 # !!! +++
print(f'\n{dir_path} \n{directory}') 


class CentralWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CentralWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("main_window.py")
        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.setWindowTitle('КБЖУ')
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ffffff;')

        self.frame_name = QFrame()
        self.frame_name.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.frame_name.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
                            border: 0px;
                            background-color: #9EFFFF;
        }''')

        self.icon_user = QLabel()

#        self.icon_user.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage('icon_app/user.png')))
        self.icon_user.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(f'{directory}/user.png')))      # +++
# +++ -->                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  

        self.label_name = QLabel('Имя')
        self.label_name.setStyleSheet('''QLabel {
                            color: #4f4a4a;
                            font-size: 20px;
        }''')

        #  Верхнее меню и имя
        self.name_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.name_layout.setSpacing(10)
        self.name_layout.addWidget(self.icon_user)
        self.name_layout.addWidget(self.label_name)
        self.name_layout.addStretch(1)
        self.frame_name.setLayout(self.name_layout)

        #  Главная форма
        self.layout_main_menu = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_main_menu.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 30)
        self.layout_main_menu.addWidget(self.frame_name, stretch=2)
        self.layout_main_menu.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(self.layout_main_menu)

        
        self.registrationWindow = RegistrationWindow(self)                           # !!! +++
        self.registrationWindow.show()                                               # !!! +++
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = CentralWidget()
    
#    win.show()                                                                      # !!! ---

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Обратите внимание, что запускать (откуда угодно) будем модуль **q1388871_main_window.py**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я понимаю, то что если я в один пакет положу все модули то все работает, но мне нужно чтобы работала так как у меня пакеты сделаны в проекте, и у меня запускается первым регистрация а потом главное окно, а вы просто все поняли местами и в один пакет положили, но у меня в настоящей программе будут десятки модулей в разных пакетах

Comment: а можно просто добавить в модуль ```main_window``` вот это ```directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'icon_app')``` и путь сделать вот так  ```self.icon_user.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(f'{directory}/user.png')))``` ?
Я проверил, все работает с моим кодом, можно ли так использовать?

Comment: @Tesla я обновил свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: @Tesla на ваш второй комментарий, скажу так, что можно по разному, но я вам показал как это делают лучшие практики.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду как лучше реализовывать переход между окнами, вы эту практику имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Tesla, да, `main` он и африке `main`. Все остальное крутится вокруг него.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо большое